# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor de un input con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Este es mi `input` y necesito obtener el valor por `JavaScript` de preferencia que sea puro y no con frameworks o si no hay otra manera ni modo.

```
<input 
  type="text" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" 
  jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" 
  tabindex="0" aria-label="Nombre" 
  value="FJ" dir="ltr" data-initial-value="FJ" 
  autofocus="" id="searchInput">
```

Comment: Puede explicarme porque negativa la pregunta?

Comment: Yo no te vote negativo, pero me parece que tu pregunta es muy simple y se puede encontrar facilmente en Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba con esto :

```
var value = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
```

O con `JQuery` :

```
var bla = $('#searchInput').val();
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Hice un pequeño código con tu input espero te sirva:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.addEventListener("click", () => {

  var input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  var valor = input.value;

  alert("El valor del campo es:"+ valor);
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-label="Nombre" value="FJ" dir="ltr" data-initial-value="FJ" autofocus="" id="searchInput">

<button id="boton">Obtner valor</button>
```